# Where to add plural 's' in two connected words

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number, numbers

I want to refer to many clients misconfiguration. I am not sure whether the s should be in the client or int he misconfiguration.

> clients misconfiguration

OR

> client misconfigurations

OR

> clients misconfigurations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to:

1. A single problem that many clients have caused, then this is singular form of misconfiguration and multiple clients.  If you are referring to the error as the misconfiguration that belongs to the client, then don't forget the [apostrophe](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/apostro.asp).  An apostrophe is not needed if there is no specific client and you are using the word "client" as an adjective to describe the misconfiguration.

Use "clients' misconfiguration"

2. Many problems caused by a single and un-named client, using client as an adjective again.  Similar to saying "user end misconfiguration" or "client side misconfiguration".  Using client to describe the type of misconfiguration, NOT server side misconfiguration.

Use "client misconfigurations"

3. Many problems generically caused by clients en mass.  Not referring specifically to clients, but describing the problems as a client problem (referring to many clients) as opposed to a server problem:

Use "client misconfigurations".

Whilst technically accurate I wouldn't use "clients' misconfigurations" because it sounds a bit of a tongue twister.  Even with many clients and many misconfigurations, it would fall to the adjective form of client or speak only of a single misconfiguration for multiple clients (ignoring the other misconfigurations).

Comment: One possible difference is that _client misconfigurations_ could be clients who are misconfigured on your part, whereas _clients’ misconfigurations_ is unambiguously things that the clients themselves have configured incorrectly.